# Solr empty query can't find the data

Tags: solr

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I tried to query the data of `status==1 and projectMaintainUserIds!=null and leadsStatus!=null` through the following statement, but the result is different from the expectation, and the returned result set is empty.

```
q=(status:1)&fq=(-projectMaintainUserIds:*) AND (-leadsStatus:12)
```

If I modify the query statement slightly, it seems to return the correct result:

```
q=(status:1)&fq=-projectMaintainUserIds:* AND -leadsStatus:12
```

I don't know why parentheses affect the results of '-filed:*' queries.

Comment: q=(status:1)&fq=-(projectMaintainUserIds:* AND leadsStatus:12)...try this

Comment: The parentheses changes that Solr can't prefix it with the set of all documents (`*:*`). Try `(*:* -projectMaintainUserIds:*) AND (*:* -leadsStatus:12)` - that way you end up with the complete set in both cases, and then the intersection between those sets. I'm not sure if `-projectMaintainUserIds:*` will resolve to the same as `-projectMaintainUserIds:[* TO *]` which has been the recommended way to find any document without a value.